# How to apply the value from specific row within the group in a column python 3.7

Tags: python-3.x, pandas-groupby

## GOAL

Use the value which is No.1 in "Group_Line" column within the group to overwrite "-" of the rest of rows in every group, without influence the group which doesn't have any "Name" value but "-".

```
    Name    Group   Group_Line NEW_Name
0   Paul    A-1      1         Paul
1   -       A-1      2         Paul
2   -       A-1      3         Paul
3   -       B-1      1          -
4   -       B-1      2          -
5   Amy     C-1      2         Amy
6   Amy     C-1      1         Amy
```

## sample data :

```
xx = pd.DataFrame({"Name": ["Paul","-","-","-","-","Amy","Amy"],
                   "Group": ["A-1","A-1","A-1","B-1","B-1","C-1","C-1"],
                   "Group_Line": ["1","3","","1","2","2","1"]
                  })
```

## Script

```
# make a key
xx = xx .assign(NAME_IND = xx['Group'].astype(str).copy() + xx['Group_Line'].astype(str).copy())
# get the value which is No.1 in "Group_Line" column within the group
yy= xx.sort_values(by=['Group','Group_Line'],ascending=True).groupby('NAME_IND').first()[["Name","NAME_IND"]]

xx["NEW_Name"] = xx['NAME_IND'].map(yy.set_index('NAME_IND')['Name']) <-- get error
```

## Error

KeyError: "['NAME_IND'] not in index"

In R can be achieve with [match(xx$NAME_KEY,xx$NAME_KEY)] by applying on "-" rows , what is the solution with python ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Reason of error is `NAME_IND` is not column, but index, what is perfect for mapping, so only specify column `Name` after `groupby` and then `map` by `Series` called `y`:

```
y= (xx.sort_values(by=['Group','Group_Line'],ascending=True)
       .groupby('NAME_IND')['Name']
       .first())
print (y)
NAME_IND
A-1        -
A-11    Paul
A-13       -
B-11       -
B-12       -
C-11     Amy
C-12     Amy
Name: Name, dtype: object
```

Alternative solution with [`DataFrame.drop_duplicates`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.drop_duplicates.html) and [`DataFrame.set_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.set_index.html):

```
y= (xx.sort_values(by=['Group','Group_Line'],ascending=True)
       .drop_duplicates('NAME_IND')
       .set_index('NAME_IND')['Name'])
print (y)
NAME_IND
A-1        -
A-11    Paul
A-13       -
B-11       -
B-12       -
C-11     Amy
C-12     Amy
Name: Name, dtype: object
```

---

```
xx["NEW_Name"] = xx['NAME_IND'].map(y)
print (xx)
   Name Group Group_Line NAME_IND NEW_Name
0  Paul   A-1          1     A-11     Paul
1     -   A-1          3     A-13        -
2     -   A-1                 A-1        -
3     -   B-1          1     B-11        -
4     -   B-1          2     B-12        -
5   Amy   C-1          2     C-12      Amy
6   Amy   C-1          1     C-11      Amy
```

EDIT:

Previous answer - possible, but overcomplicated - first set index to column and then set same column to index:

Reason is `NAME_IND` is index, so possible solutions are `as_index=False` parameter in [`DataFrame.groupby`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html):

```
yy= (xx.sort_values(by=['Group','Group_Line'],ascending=True)[["Name","NAME_IND"]]
       .groupby('NAME_IND', as_index=False)
       .first())
```

Or [`DataFrame.reset_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.reset_index.html):

```
yy= (xx.sort_values(by=['Group','Group_Line'],ascending=True)[["Name","NAME_IND"]]
       .groupby('NAME_IND')
       .first()
       .reset_index())

print (yy)
  NAME_IND  Name
0      A-1     -
1     A-11  Paul
2     A-13     -
3     B-11     -
4     B-12     -
5     C-11   Amy
6     C-12   Amy
```

Also is possible use [`DataFrame.drop_duplicates`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.drop_duplicates.html):

```
yy= (xx.sort_values(by=['Group','Group_Line'],ascending=True)[["Name","NAME_IND"]]
       .drop_duplicates('NAME_IND'))

print (yy)
   Name NAME_IND
2     -      A-1
0  Paul     A-11
1     -     A-13
3     -     B-11
4     -     B-12
6   Amy     C-11
5   Amy     C-12

xx["NEW_Name"] = xx['NAME_IND'].map(yy.set_index('NAME_IND')['Name'])
```

Comment: jezrael thank you , although i made a critical mistake of my question that should not add "Group_Line" as a key but your answer rightfully solved the error.